# Combine SELECT and ASK queries in a same query

Tags: sparql, triples, blazegraph

Context: 14M triples, Blazegraph workbench. I'm currently attempting to design queries which combine SELECT and ASK. More exactly, I want to select results in my graph where an assumption is true.

For my example, imagine I've many books which have one author and one editor. I want to select the book from the author which his book is linked through random path length property to the `client#1`.

In my case, with my data, it takes a lot of time to realise the query directly like that:

```sql
SELECT ?id_book
WHERE {?id_book prefix:hasAuthor :author#1.
        ?id_book prefix:linkedToEditor*/prefix:hasClient :client#1}
ORDER by ?id_book
```

To reduce the time of calculus (x 1:1000), I'm using a script to realise these queries successively. The script selects the books which have as author the author n°1:

```sql
SELECT ?id_book
WHERE {?id_book prefix:hasAuthor :author#1}
ORDER by ?id_book
```

And I ask for each result for 1 to n (`id_book#1`, `id_book#2`, ..., `id_book#n`) if it's linked to client n°1:

```sql
ASK {id_book#i prefix:linkedToEditor*/prefix:hasClient :client#1}
```

The SELECT query followed by the ASK query is far faster than the first SELECT query for the same results. I don't want to explore all the possibilities of `?id_book prefix:linkedToEditor*/prefix:hasClient :client#1`; I just want to save results where the link exists. I tried with FILTER EXISTS or two SELECT queries, but the query times are similarly long:

```sql
SELECT ?id_book
WHERE {?id_book prefix:hasAuthor :author#1.}
FILTER EXIST {?id_book prefix:linkedToEditor*/prefix:hasClient :client#1}
ORDER by ?id_book
```

or

```sql
SELECT ?id_book
WHERE {?id_book prefix:linkedToEditor*/prefix:hasClient :client#1.
    {SELECT ?id_book
        WHERE {?id_book prefix:hasAuthor :author#1.}
    }
}
```

How can I optimise my queries into one query?

Comment: As suggested in the answer below, your experience is rather surprising. I might suggest you consider and perhaps test with some different RDF stores and/or SPARQL processors. There are a number to choose from...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit surprising that there's such a difference in your query times;  a SPARQL engine should probably be able optimize the query to perform the simple part first, and then do the more complicated query property path afterward.  The ordering could also cause some time increase, and it's really not important if you're just interested in boolean results.

At any rate, since nested queries are performed innermost first, you can sort of force the "do this first, then do that" by nesting the queries like this:

```sql
select ?id_book {
  #-- first, get the books by author one
  { select ?id_book { ?id_book prefix:hasAuthor :author#1 } }

  #-- then, then check that the book is related to client one
  ?id_book prefix:linkedToEditor*/prefix:hasClient :client#1
}
order by ?id_book
```

Comment: This query takes a lot of time in my case. I think the SPARQL engine tests every possibility in the second query and then compare with the first query to give the results. It seems to be this case for the Blazegraph's SPARQL engine.

Comment: @Cyril subqueries are supposed to be evaluated innermost first.  This *should* find a some ?id_book values and then check each one.  If it seems like your engine is doing something different, what happens if you exchange the position of these queries?  I.e., put the outer one inside?  Also, is there any change if you don't order the results?

Comment: I better understand the behavior of my query. With the query you proposed, I get correctly the `?id_book with the author#1`, but the second query determines all paths where ?id_book verified `linkedToEditor*/hasClient`; it's take too much time. And could use DISTINCT but DISTINCT test all paths and limit the results where ?id_book are DISTINCT: it's take the same time.

Comment: The best would be to limit the second query to one result for each ?id_book found in the first query. In my case, the second query has to much solutions (too much intermediate editors) and it takes too much time..

Comment: @Cyril in light of that, does changing the outermost select into `select distinct ?id_book ...` help?

Comment: Just for information, the request inside the FILTER EXISTS has more than 10 thousands of solutions. This query alone takes more than 600 000 ms to give results on my PC (mac pro 8go RAM and 4 core). The DISTINCT query just selects into all results the results with distinct `?id_book`. The calculus is not limit to one per `?id_book`. It would be perfect if the query into the FILTER EXISTS could be limited to ONE result. I send my data and my procedures to the Blazegraph'staff. They're reactive and the product is very good. I think they'll have an answer.

Comment: @Cyril  If the only value that you're selecting is ?id_book, then doing `SELECT DISTINCT ?id_book ...` would let the SPARQL engine to stop after examining just one of those "10 thousands of solutions" for each candidate value of ?id_book, since that would be enough to include the value, and examining more of those "10 thousands of solutions" can't add anything else to the query results.

Comment: @Cyril *"The DISTINCT query just selects into all results the results with distinct ?id_book."* Note that I suggested changing the **outermost** query to select distinct.  That is, doing `select distinct ?id_book { { select ?id_book ...} ?id_book path value }`.  Then, the engine could determine that only one match for `?id_book path value` is needed, since additional paths don't add anything. But now that you mention it, doing distinct in the *inner* query would mean that you're not repeating any values of ?id_book there, so distinct in both places might help. (Inner distinct might help more?)

Comment: At the moment with my config, with or without DISTINCT even when I switch the inner/outer query order => the result is the same in terms of time and calculus in the server side. I'm waiting for the comment of the staff.